# Can't connect to shadowsocks proxy visa proxychains

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy, dropbox

I live in China. I am trying to use proxychains to run the dropbox installer through my shadowsocks proxy on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am using shadowsocks-libev and I am able to connect to a blocked site (google for example) using firefox.

I am using proxychains4 from the repos and I have set the proxy in the config as follows:

> socks5  127.0.0.1       1080

But when launching the dropbox installer via proxychains4 as follows:

> proxychains4 dropbox start -i

It simply times out.

I am also not able to ping a blocked site through proxychains4.

Pinging a site with is not censored works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get proxychains working but I was able to install dropbox by temporarily using the free proxy tool 'lantern' to run the dropbox installation. Once installed I was able to use dropbox's proxy settings to use shadowsocks.